# Расширить динамический массив

Tags: массивы, c++

Здравствуйте! Есть дин. массив из н элементов. Нужно его расширить... Не просто взять и выделить в другой области памяти пересозданный этот же массив, а расширить имеющийся(дописать новые элементы в хвост)... Как это сделать?
Делал так:

```
`d_WB=(UserData*)realloc(d_WB, count_of_WB_herroy*sizeof(UserData));`
```

Полазил в памяти и, похоже, массив не расширяется, а пересоздается...

Comment: да, он будет пересоздаваться, если памяти не хватает.

Расширить не всегда получиться. Может выделять заведомо больше памяти?

Кстати, раз используете с++, то используйте `std::vector<UserData>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для начала: на C++ не пользуются `malloc` и `realloc`, память выделяется через `new`/`delete`. Ручное управление памяти тоже прерогатива чистого C, в C++ специально для вашего случая есть `std::vector`.

Да, а расширить массив *гарантированно* на том же месте в принципе невозможно: что если память сразу за массивом уже занята?

Если вам нужно такое, у вас что-то неверно в дизайне. Расскажите, какую настоящую цель вы преследуете. Наверняка это делается по-другому.

Comment: > Да, а расширить массив на том же месте в принципе невозможно:

а если есть? противоречите немножко сами себе.

Comment: у меня в box2d жестко забивается адрес начала массива. Вообщем в этом и проблема... Выделю заведомо больше памяти... Спасибо!

Comment: Да, неточно выразился. Переформулирую.

Comment: @Alerr: а почему у вас там адрес массива, а не `std::vector`?

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я знаю, то в vector создается новый массив, в два раза больше предыдущего, переписывается и в него дописывается нужное количество данных, а предыдущий удаляется.